# How to use variable in

Tags: python

Using pandevice, I have developed a script to create objects, services, etc. on Palo Alto firewalls.  My script currently use several blocks of code to do each creations, independently from each other.  However, I'd like to create a function to generalize this task, and diminish the number of lines in my script.

So what I'd like to do is to be able to use a variable to build the pandevice class I will use.

```
def check_obj(PanObjectType,name,value):

    # Retrieve list of objects from FW
    fw_root = PanObjectType + ".refreshall(fw)"

    print (fw_root)

    for obj in fw_root:

        print (obj)

check_obj("Tag","value1","value2")
```

When executed, the value of fw_root is actually correctly set to Tag.refreshall(fw), but the loop is going through each letter of the variable, while what I intend to do is to execute this command, and loop through the result.

Comment: Please post your entire code. This will make it easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating strings doesn't execute the code in them. You need to call the method outside quotes.

```
fw_root = PanObjectType.refreshall(fw)
```

Then call it with the variable, not a string:

```
check_obj(Tag, "value1", "value2")
```

Comment: Removing the quote actually solved the problem, thank you.